# Creating balanced bootstrap resamples in caret

Tags: resampling, caret, statistics-bootstrap, imbalanced-data

I'm using `caret` to compare models for a classification problem with nested CV. Vfold in the outer loop and bootstrap (500 replicates) in the inner loop. I get this error after training knn:

`Warning: There were missing values in resampled performance measures.`

Which I believe comes from the fact that some resamples have zero items of the class of interest in the holdout sample, yielding `NA` for Sensitivity and ROC. My question is: Is there any way to ensure that items from this class are present in every bootstrap resample? Kind of what the `CreateDataPartition` function does (I believe this is also called stratified bootstrap?).

If not, how should we proceed with this? (In terms of comparing model performance on the same resamples)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I couldn't find a way to do this within `caret` but here is a workaround using `rsample` package. The point is to compute the resamples before and feed this information to `trainControl` function via `index` and `indexOut` arguments, previous conversion to `caret` format.

```
indices=bootstraps(train,times=50,strata="class_of_interest")
indices=rsample2caret(indices)
train_control <- trainControl(method="boot",number=50,index=indices$index,indexOut = indices$indexOut)
```

Hope this helps.